# Subexpression failure

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to output some data to some files, where the filename is the first character of a variable. I think it's a problem with the subexpression near the end.

```
$var = 123,456,789
echo abc > "$($env:userprofile)\dir\$($var[0].substring(0,1)).txt"
```

I formatted this according to what I read but it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: Please post the actual errors you're getting. FWIW you can't call `.Substring()` on an integer. You need to convert it to a string first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target directory does not exist, then using a redirect operator `>` will fail.

```
$var = 123,456,789 #this is an array of ints
$Path = $env:UserProfile + "\dir\$($var[0].ToString().Substring(0,1)).txt"

If (-not (Test-Path -Path $Path)) {New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType 'File' -Force}

'abc' > $Path
```

Comment: Why does the (Test-Path -Path $Path) exist without the $ before it?

Comment: @Lumify Could you clarify what you mean?  There's no need for a string subexpression when you're testing a case that  doesn't need a string.